# Проблема с движениями и анимациями в Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда в коде прописана только IDLE анимация, то он персонаж и бегает с IDLE анимацией и стоит. А как только я подключаю в коде анимацию бега, то он просто стоит, а анимация проигрывается.

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine; 

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
   public float speed; 
   public float jumpForce; 
   private float moveInput; 

   private bool facingRight;

   private Rigidbody2D rb; 

   private bool isGrounded; 
   public Transform feetPos; 
   public float checkRadius; 
   public LayerMask whatIsGround; 

   private Animator anim; 

   void Start() 
   { 
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
      anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); 
   } 

   void FixedUpdate() 
   {
    
      if (moveInput == 0) 
         anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);  
      else 
         anim.SetBool("isRunning", true); 

       moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); 
       rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y); 
       if (facingRight == false && moveInput > 0) 
           Flip(); 
       else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0) 
           Flip(); 

          
         
   } 

   private void Update() 
   { 
      isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround); 

      if (isGrounded == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
          rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce; 
   } 

   void Flip() 
   { 
      facingRight = !facingRight; 
      Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale; 
      Scaler.x *= -1; 
      transform.localScale = Scaler; 
   }
```

}

Comment: `if (moveInput == 0)` тут сравнение числа с плавающей точкой на равенство, причем значения, полученного на предыдущей итерации.